# vue.js watchers' order of precedence in parent-child relation

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In vue.js I have .vue component which has a watched data property isRunning.  This component has a child component which also watches isRunning (accessed through its binding).  Can I be assured that the watcher for the parent will be executed before the child's watcher?

Comment: Why don't you test it by putting `console.log` in both watchers and run it several times? I'm quite sure the parent watcher will be executed first, because it needs to be created before the child component. When it is created (in terms of code the `created` hook is called), the watchers are set.

Comment: Yes I could test a simple case but that wouldn't necessarily prove consistency in a more complex example which is why I need an informed position